# How to merge two SQL/MySQL queries in to a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I checked several post related my subject, but I cannot find my answer. I also posted similar question but can't get any answer so I prepared posting again.

Because my table's columns have same values and want to count by team and HTFT values.

**Expected result :**

| Team Totals | HTFT(1/1) | HTFT(X/1) | HTFT(X/X) | HTFT(2/2) | HTFT(X/2) | HTFT(1/X) | HTFT(2/X) | HTFT(2/1) | HTFT(1/2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adana Demirspor | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Alanyaspor | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Altay | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Antalyaspor | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Beşiktaş | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Çaykur Rizespor | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Fatih Karagümrük | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Fenerbahçe | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Galatasaray | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Gaziantep | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Giresunspor | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Göztepe | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Hatayspor | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| İstanbul Başakşehir | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Kasımpaşa | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Kayserispor | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Konyaspor | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Sivasspor | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Trabzonspor | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Yeni Malatyaspor | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

---

I have below fiddle link that have my tables, sample database and two queries.

[My Sample database fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81f6811d831046a7194c392ce1918672)

I want to merge two queries in one query is it possible?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH
Home AS (
SELECT m.home_team_id AS team_id,t.team_name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h 1/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h X/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h X/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h 2/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h X/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h 1/X',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h 2/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h 2/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'h 1/2'
    FROM matches m 
    INNER JOIN teams t on m.home_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY 1,2
),
Away AS (
SELECT m.away_team_id AS team_id,t.team_name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a 1/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a X/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a X/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a 2/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a X/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a 1/X',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a 2/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a 2/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'a 1/2'
    FROM matches m
    INNER JOIN teams t on m.away_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT *
FROM Home
JOIN Away USING (team_id, team_name)
ORDER BY 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c7d73ac3d6f892d7c9d415cf3baef3d

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
SELECT
Home as Team
,SUM(1by1) as '1/1'
,SUM(Xby1) as 'X/1'
,SUM(XbyX) AS 'X/X'
,SUM(2by2) AS '2/2'
,SUM(Xby2) AS 'X/2'
,SUM(1byX) AS '1/X'
,SUM(2byX) AS '2/X'
,SUM(2by1) AS '2/1'
,SUM(1by2) AS '1/2'
FROM
(
SELECT m.home_team_id ,t.team_name as Home,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'XbyX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1byX',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2byX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by2'
    FROM matches m 
    INNER JOIN teams t on m.home_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY m.home_team_id,Home

union all

SELECT m.away_team_id,t.team_name as Away,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'XbyX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1byX',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2byX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by2'
    FROM matches m
    INNER JOIN teams t on m.away_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY m.away_team_id,Away
)A
GROUP BY TEAM
order by 1
;
```

query with team id filter,

```
SELECT
home_team_id as team_id
,Home as Team
,SUM(1by1) as '1/1'
,SUM(Xby1) as 'X/1'
,SUM(XbyX) AS 'X/X'
,SUM(2by2) AS '2/2'
,SUM(Xby2) AS 'X/2'
,SUM(1byX) AS '1/X'
,SUM(2byX) AS '2/X'
,SUM(2by1) AS '2/1'
,SUM(1by2) AS '1/2'
FROM
(
SELECT m.home_team_id ,t.team_name as Home,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'XbyX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1byX',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2byX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by2'
    FROM matches m 
    INNER JOIN teams t on m.home_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY m.home_team_id,Home

union all

SELECT m.away_team_id,t.team_name as Away,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'XbyX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Xby2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1byX',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2byX',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2by1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1by2'
    FROM matches m
    INNER JOIN teams t on m.away_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY m.away_team_id,Away
)A
where home_team_id=8
GROUP BY TEAM, home_team_id
order by 1
;
```

Comment: Dear Abishek VK, thank you so much for great answer, it's perfect. In your same query how can I search by team (example as : where team_id = 8), which area do I write this ?

Comment: Hi Cimmy, you can add team_id in the outer select list and group by and use same same in a where clause to filter.  Added it for you in the answer. 
If the answer is working for you please accept the solution

Comment: Sure I will accept it. Can you pls. update your query as what I requested above? Because I tried it, but I cannot placement correctly..

Comment: Added the query . Please check